# What $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not flat module in the ring $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$

Tags: modules

Let $R=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ be a ring and the ideal $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is not flat module since $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is generated by a nilpotent element how to prove it?

Comment: If nobody has answered your question, and you need to improve it, you should just edit it instead of deleting and reposting. Reposting to get rid of feedback you got before is usually construed as abuse of the system. Perhaps you didn't know, but if you do it again, I'll assume it's abuse and flag accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have an embedding $0\rightarrow 2Z/4Z\rightarrow Z/4Z$. A $Z/Z4Z$ bilinear form $b$ defined on $2Z/4X\times 2Z/4Z$ is zero. Since you will $b(2,2)=4b(1,1)$. This implies that the tensor product $2Z/4Z\otimes 2Z/4Z$ is zero.